# probabilility point closer to distance circle

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics

the probability that the point is closer to the distance to the center of the circle than to the circumference is  $\frac{1}{4}$  
 find probability: 
(A) When several points are selected sequentially in this circle, find the probability that the fourth point will be closer to the center of the circle than the circumference for the first time.

(B) Probability to obtain the point will be closer to the center of the circle than the circumference for the first time 0.90 or more,  at least how many points should be selected?

my attempt: 
A.$(1- \frac{1}{4})^3  \frac{1}{4}= \frac{27}{256}$ 
2.$(\frac{3}{4})^{n-1}  \frac{1}{4}\ge 0.90 $ then i just need to find n 

am i right for number 2? But seem the right answer for b is with $\sum_{I=1}^n \frac{3}{4}^{n-1} \frac{1}{4} \ge 0.90$ why with summation(?)

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Yeah looks right.

Comment: @saulspatz  thanks but the right answer seems with summation notation(?) why is that(?)

Answer (score 1):

As to part 2), this is another way of arriving at the correct answer.  The probability that the first point closer to the center than the circumference is the $k$ point selected is, as we have said, $\left(\frac34\right)^{k-1}\frac14.$  If want the probability that at least one of $n$ points selected is closer to the center, that is same as the probability that first closer to the center is point $1$ or point $2$, and so on up to point $n$.  These events are mutually exclusive (only one point can be first) so the probability that at least one of $n$ point is closer to the center is the sum of the probabilities:$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac34\right)^{k-1}\frac14=\frac14{\left(\frac34\right)^n-1\over\frac34-1}=1-\left(\frac34\right)^n$$

You have a mistake in the way you have written the summation in the question.  The exponent should be $I-1$, not $n-1$.

Comment: thankyou so much!, so at least one point mean the first point closer to center can be first, second,, up to n?